# Protractor : xlsx-template Error cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, protractor

I am using xlsx-template to generate Excel files on the base of custom template that I have created. But I am getting error while creating a new excel file out of template

**Below is the error :**

> E/launcher - Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>
> E/launcher - TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at Workbook.module.exports.Workbook.loadSheet (E:\latest-code\latest\test automation\node_modules\xlsx-template\lib\index.js:373:38)
>       at Workbook.module.exports.Workbook.substitute (E:\latest-code\latest\test automation\node_modules\xlsx-template\lib\index.js:123:26)
>       at E:\latest-code\latest\test automation\config\index.js:117:16
>       at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:416:3)

**Code Snippet:**

```
 var XlsxTemplate = require('xlsx-template'),
      fs = require('fs'),
      path = require('path');

        describe("excel", function() {

          it("excel file", function() {
            console.log('inside after each...');
            console.log(__dirname);
            fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'Template.xlsx'), function(err, data) {

              var template = new XlsxTemplate(data);
              var values = {
                testcase: [{
                  id: 1,
                  name: "login",
                  status: "pass"
                }, {
                  id: 2,
                  name: "logout",
                  status: "fail"
                }, {
                  id: 3,
                  name: "searchbox",
                  status: "pass"
                }]
              }
              console.log(values);
              template.substitute(1, values);

              console.log('excel data');

              var newData = template.generate();

              fs.writeFileSync('test1.xlsx', newData, 'binary');
            });
          })
```

Am I missing any other configuration for xlsx-template. Please advice how to get rid of this error as I am not able to resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Guys... Any help appreciated.  Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue with xlsx-template that I have installed . Actually in the loadSheet method of xlsx-template index.js file I was having `i < self.sheet.length` in for loop which should be `i < self.sheets.length`. I installed the xlsx-template again and now its working fine.

Thanks all for your great help:)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the `fs.readFile` finds the file ?
When you use `template.substitute` the first param is the sheet number.
If no sheets are found, the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at Workbook.module.exports.Workbook.loadSheet` appends ...

What do you have in `err` in the callback of `fs.readFile` ?

Y.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem comes from `newData`.

`Template.generate` doesn't return binary data.

On `NodeJs` you can use :

```
var tplt = template.generate();
var binaryTplt = new Buffer(tplt, 'binary');
fs.writeFile(fileName, binaryTplt, function (err) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log('XLS file saved : ' + fileName);
});
```

Hope it will help you!

Y.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually I am getting this error on  `template.substitute(1, values)` . 
As also can we seen from error its giving me error at 
`Workbook.module.exports.Workbook.substitute (E:\latest-code\latest\test automation\node_modules\xlsx-template\lib\index.js:123:26) `